# Как сделать плагин слайдера multiple?

Tags: jquery, slider, плагин

Всем привет!
Написан jQuery-плагин для слайдера(слайдшоу) по классической структуре:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.slider = function(optUser) {
        var optDefault = {};
        settings = $.extend({}, optDefault, optUser);
        return this.each(function () {

        // Код слайдера

        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Запуск слайдера
    $('#slider').slider({optUser});

Никаких дополнительных методов не использовал.
Всё нормально работает. НО только если запущен один слайдер на страничке. Запуская два слайдера на одной страничке, работают они некорректно - этого и следовало ожидать.
Происходит перекрещивание значений (скажем, выбор нового активного слайда становится для обоих активным), т.е. значения каждого слайдера (экземпляра) не фиксируются.
Возникла необходимость сделать плагин multiple. Как я понял существует несколько способов:

1. Создать систему для пространства имён и использовать .data для ключевых значений (но проанализировав такие слайдеры, представленные в Интернете -  убедился, что работают не совсем корректно, вопреки словам разработчиков).
2. [Вариант с "Классами"](http://www.virgentech.com/blog/2009/10/building-object-oriented-jquery-plugin.html).
3. [Вариант с "Классами" и свойством .prototype](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/05/creating-highly-configurable-jquery-plugins/).

Помогите разобраться какой из вариантов более оптимальный?
Будут ли во втором варианте фиксироваться все значения данного экземпляра не пересекаясь с другим экземпляром слайдера?

Благодарю всех за ответы!!!

ИТОГ РЕШЕНИЯ:

Ответ на свой вопрос не могу пока написать из-за отсутствия нужного количества очков, написал в качестве дополнения здесь.

За ночь я разобрался со своим вопросом...
Решение оказалось неожиданным для меня.

Проблема заключалась не в структуре самого плагина, а в небольших косяках, которые я допустил:

- для всех переменных, которые, так
  сказать, индивидуальны (присуще
  только объекту, для которого вызван
  плагин) требуется локальная область
  переменных (у меня это было не везде,
  поэтому и возникали эти
  "перекрещивания" - второй вызов
  плагина рушил работу первого).
- исправил недочёты при задании
  селекторов при поиске объектов внутри
  самого плагина. Всё только на классах
  и id, который нужно корректно
  использовать. Были такого рода
  небольшие косяки, пример:
  $('#caption') - неверно(при поиске
  блока для поиска подписей. $("outer

  ## caption") - верно; $this.find('#caption') - верно ($this- jQuery-объект слайдера);

И самый главный сюрприз, что при исправлении этих косяков два слайдера работали на одной странице корректно даже при моей изначальной структуре. Т.е. я не менял структуру плагина и не создавал новых объектов через new. Получается каждый вызов просто выдавал тот же экземпляр работающего слайдера.

Конечно, с позиции реализации ООП и наглядного понимания кода (если можно так выразиться) это неверно насколько я понял. Каждый вызов должен создавать свой экземпляр "класса" (применительно для js) со своими приватными или публичными методами и свойствами (по варианту 2).

!!! Поэтому с исправлением всех косяков я остановился на структуре - вариант 2.

[@Deonis](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/4058/deonis), Вам спасибо. Посмотрев на Ваш наглядный пример начал гуглить в нужную сторону)))

Comment: Я бы ориентировался на здравомыслящего пользователя. То есть, того, кто не будет использовать два и более элемента на странице с одинаковым ID. В связи с этим, я бы рассматривал вариант подключения только по классу.

Comment: [@Deonis](http://hashcode.ru/users/4058/deonis), спасибо за мнение. Т.е. по Вашему мнению это второй вариант. А Вы случайно не подскажите, как правильно организовать независимые друг от друга экземпляры? Или строчка во втором варианте:
<code> var myplugin = new MyPlugin(this, options); </code>
это и есть уже создание экземпляра и любые высчитываемые значения для него  не будут пересекаться с другим экземпяром?
Если исходить, что осуществляются два вызова плагина на два элемента с разными ID.

Comment: @MadMonkey, Может я не правильно вас понял, но если вы имеете в виду возможность подключения плагина к разным элементам с индивидуальными параметрами, то да - [такой вариант можно использовать](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/QHbJP/1/).

Comment: [@Deonis](http://hashcode.ru/users/4058/deonis), поняли Вы меня совершенно верно. Спасибо. Сейчас попробую Вашу структуру.
Пробовал второй вариант из мною перечисленных, но не работает. Второй вызов, так сказать рушит работу первого. Видимо, я немного не догоняю, как адаптировать под несколько запусков... но буду пытаться понять.
Спасибо ещё раз за идею. По результату Вашей идеи тогда отпишу))

Comment: [@Deonis](http://hashcode.ru/users/4058/deonis), предложенная Вами структура наверное правильная. Но в моём случае проблема оказалась ещё и в правильном сохранении расчётных значений, применимых к экземпляру.
Поэтому исправляю свои косяки... надеюсь всё получится.
Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

РЕШЕНИЕ:
Ответ написал в качестве дополнения к ответу.