# 2 CSS слайдера на странице не работают почему?

Tags: javascript, css

Есть файл styles.css и исполняемый блок:

```
<div id="slideShowContainer">
    <div id="slideShow">
        <div id="pictures">
            <img src="img/photos/picture1.png" alt="" />
            <img src="img/photos/picture2.png" alt="" />
            <img src="img/photos/picture3.png" alt="" />
            <img src="img/photos/picture4.png" alt="" />
            <img src="img/photos/picture5.png" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <a id="previousLink" href="#">&raquo;</a>
    <a id="nextLink" href="#">&laquo;</a>
</div>

        </div>
```

1 работает на странице, 2 не работают на странице.

Вопрос  Что нужно изменить что бы работали 2 и 3 и т.д. блоки на одной странице?

```
Скрипт
/ Действия выполняются после загрузки DOM
$(document).ready(function() {

  var z = 0;                // Переменная для хранения значения свойства z-index
  var inAnimation = false;  // Флаг, сигнализирующий о выполнении анимации

  $('#pictures img').each(function() {      // Устанавливаем начальные значения свойства z-index
    z++;                                // В перменной будет храниться максимальное значение свойства z-index
    $(this).css('z-index', z);          // Присваиваем увеличенное значение свойства z-index для <img>
  });

  function swapFirstLast(isFirst) {

    if(inAnimation) return false;       // Если уже выполняется анимация, то прерываем дальнейшее выполнение функции
    else inAnimation = true;            // Устанавливаем флаг, сигнализирующий о выполенении анимации

    var processZindex, direction, newZindex, inDeCrease; // Переменные для технических нужд

    if(isFirst) { processZindex = z; direction = '-'; newZindex = 1; inDeCrease = 1; }  // Устанавливаем перменные для действия "следующий"
    else { processZindex = 1; direction = ''; newZindex = z; inDeCrease = -1; }         // Устанавливаем перменные для действия "предыдущий"

    $('#pictures img').each(function() {                // Цикл по всем изображениям

      if($(this).css('z-index') == processZindex) {     // Проверяем, нужно ли обрабатывать изображение

        // Анимируем перемещение изображения над/под галереей (предполагается, что все изображения имеют одинаковую высоту)
        $(this).animate({ 'top' : direction + $(this).height() + 'px' }, 'slow', function() { 
          $(this).css('z-index', newZindex)                 // Устанавливаем новое значение свойства z-index
            .animate({ 'top' : '0' }, 'slow', function() {  // Анимируем движение изображения обратно на свое место
              inAnimation = false;                          // Сбрасываем флаг
            });
        });
      } else {  // Нет изображений для обработки, нужно только увеличть/уменьшить значение свойства z-index
        $(this).animate({ 'top' : '0' }, 'slow', function() {                       
          $(this).css('z-index', parseInt($(this).css('z-index')) + inDeCrease);    // Увеличиваем или уменьшаем значение свойства z-index
        });
      }
    });

    return false; // Прерываем дальнейшую обработку события
  }

  $('#previousLink').click(function() {
    return swapFirstLast(false);    // Переводим первое изображение на последнюю позицию
  });

  $('#nextLink').click(function() {
    return swapFirstLast(true);     // Переводим последнее изображение на первую позицию
  });
});
```

Comment: А причем тут Java?! Может сначала научимся отделять Java от JavaScript?

Comment: Выскочила подсказка нажал - не заметил!

Answer (score 1):

Вместо id-шников , поставьте в соответствующих блоках классы, и измените селектор.

```
<div class="pictures">
   //
</div>
<a class="previousLink" href="#">&raquo;</a>
<a class="nextLink" href="#">&laquo;</a>
// и т.д.
```

**JS**

```
$('.pictures img')
$('.previousLink')
$('.nextLink')
```

P.S. Кстати, часок назад, уже обсуждалась похожая проблема. [Гляньте этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/169689/jquery-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-multiple), возможно, что будет полезен.

Comment: Спасибо,  Deonis !!!